# Java Byte/byte array space efficiency comparison

Tags: java, generics, space-efficiency

I need to create a space efficient 2D array for a large number of 8 bit values. I began writing my class using a few layers of abstraction and generics to allow for code reuse. Once I got to implementing the concrete class it occurred to me I cannot pass in a primitive type as a generic class argument and I would have to use a wrapper class. Because I am concerned about space efficiency, I need to know: *what is the space efficiency difference between a* `Byte` *array using the wrapper class compared to a primitive* `byte` *array*?

Comment: but why use generics on 8 bit values ? what is the purpose of different types if you explicitly store 8 bit values ?

Comment: @giorashc I might want to later store `objects` or `ints` in the same unique way I am currently storing 8 bit values, The 2D array is the concrete storage implementation but the class's data structure access control is unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, primitives are light-weight compared to corresponding Wrapper class objects.

You can read about it here :
   [Primitives vs Wrappers](http://www.glenmccl.com/perfj_006.htm)

Comment: Thanks Giorashc, I was trying to do this at the same time. I still need to know how to create links on this site!

Comment: Just click the earth icon, paste your link, confirm and than fill the description between the brackets

Comment: @INdoknight see the FAQ for that.

Answer (score 4):

Accroding to http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

byte[] size ~= 12 + length

Byte[] size ~= 12 + 20 * length  (20 = 16 + 4 the size of 1 Byte object + 4 bytes reference)

so, Byte[] may take 20 times more memory than byte[]. It is actually maximum, it depends on the way you create a Byte. new Byte is always a new Object, Byte.valueOf is always a cached instance. It also depends on CPU, for x64 each reference takes 8 bytes.

Comment: I don't know whether `Byte` objects are cached, or just integers, but even if they're not I would think that for any size `Byte` array one could use a static `Byte[256]` to hold an instance of each value; the overhead for that would be fixed at ~4096 bytes, each `Byte[]` array that used cached instances would typically take 4 bytes per entry.

Comment: It is 4 bytes for each reference to a Byte object which is 16 bytes. As for caching it depends on how you create it. new Byte is always a new object.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev: The reference takes 8 bytes on a 64-bit JVM without compressed OOPs.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this other question:
[Wrappers of primitive types in arraylist vs arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557704/wrappers-of-primitive-types-in-arraylist-vs-arrays)

> The big issue with double versus Double is that the latter adds some amount of memory overhead -- 8 bytes per object on a Sun 32-bit JVM, possibly more or less on others. Then you need another 4 bytes (8 on a 64-bit JVM) to refer to the object.
>
> So, assuming that you have 1,000,000 objects, the differences are as follows:
>
> > double[1000000]
>
> 8 bytes per entry; total = 8,000,000 bytes
>
> > Double[1000000]
>
> 16 bytes per object instance + 4 bytes per reference; total = 20,000,000 bytes
>
> Whether or not this matters depends very much on your application. Unless you find yourself running out of memory, assume that it doesn't matter.